# Python to ruby conversion

Tags: python, ruby, http, post

Hi guys I have a python script that posts some data to google and gets back response. The script is below

```
net, cid, lac = 24005, 40242, 62211
import urllib
a = '000E00000000000000000000000000001B0000000000000000000000030000'
b = hex(cid)[2:].zfill(8) + hex(lac)[2:].zfill(8)
c = hex(divmod(net,100)[1])[2:].zfill(8) + hex(divmod(net,100)[0])[2:].zfill(8)
string = (a + b + c + 'FFFFFFFF00000000').decode('hex')
try:
  data = urllib.urlopen('http://www.google.com/glm/mmap',string)
  r = data.read().encode('hex')
  print r
except:
  print 'connect error'
```

I want to get the same response with a ruby script. I am not able to form the request properly and I always get the badimplementation error or http 501 error. Could you tell me where the mistake is at? (The ruby script is attached below).

```
require 'net/http'
def fact(mnc,mcc,cid,lac)
  a = '000E00000000000000000000000000001B0000000000000000000000030000'
  b = cid.to_s(16).rjust(8,'0') + lac.to_s(16).rjust(8,'0')
  c = mnc.to_s(16).rjust(8,'0') + mcc.to_s(16).rjust(8,'0')
  string = [a + b + c + 'FFFFFFFF00000000'].pack('H*')
  url = URI.parse('http://www.google.com/glm/mmap')
  resp = Net::HTTP.post_form(url,string)
  print resp
end
puts fact(5,240,40242,62211)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From the documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html#method-c-post_form):

> Posts HTML form data to the specified URI object. The form data must be provided as a **Hash mapping from String to String**.

You have to pass the parameters, if I understood that correctly, on the form:
`{"param1" => "value1", "param2"=>"value2"}`

I just didn't understand what are the names of the parameters you are passing on your request.

Here are some usage examples for the method Net::HTTP::post_form, also from the official doc:

Ex 1:

```
uri = URI('http://www.example.com/search.cgi')
res = Net::HTTP.post_form(uri, 'q' => 'ruby', 'max' => '50')
puts res.body
```

Ex2:

```
uri = URI('http://www.example.com/search.cgi')
res = Net::HTTP.post_form(uri, 'q' => ['ruby', 'perl'], 'max' => '50')
puts res.body
```

[Link to the examples](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html)

Hope it helps

**edit:** function that accepts a String as a parameter to the post request: [Net::HTTP::request_post](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html#method-i-request_post)

Comment: #<Net::HTTPNotImplemented:0x107ffa0e8>nil I get this error always.

Comment: Also I should not post as a key value pair according to the google api. I should just post the HEX string as you can see in the python script

Comment: So you cannot use post_form, use Net::HTTP.request_post, instead. It takes a string as a parameter. Try that, if the server still responds with 501, see the actual request that was made and compare that with the request generated by the python script.